# Meteor: In template rendered event selecting multiple elements to become draggable not working

Tags: jquery-ui, meteor, draggable, meteor-blaze

**Update 2:** A The following [repo](https://github.com/camelCaseD/meteor-templateInstance.findAll-bug) on github shows the problem.

**Update 1:** Calling `@firstNode` in `Template.editor.rendered` returns `<div class="editor"></div>`.

I have the following template:

```
<template name="editor">
  <div class="editor">
    {{#each objects}}
        <div class="object">{{content}}</div>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

The data is provided by iron-router in the data callback.


The coffeescript for my template:

```
Template.editor.rendered = ->
  @findAll('.object').draggable()
```

When I go into my browser and try to drag one of the objects I get the text selection cursor and begin to select the text with the div instead of the object being dragged. So what is wrong and how can I get the drag and drop to work?

**The drag and drop functionality is being provided by jquery-ui. Which is installed as a smart package.**

*Also feel free to edit the title of this post as I had a tough time coming up with one that made sense*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to abstract `<div class="object">{{content}}</div>` into a seperate template like so:

```
<template name="object">
  <div class="object">{{content}}</div>
</template>
```

Then change

```
Template.editor.rendered = ->
  @findAll('.object').draggable()
```

to

```
Template.object.rendered = ->
  @findAll('.object').draggable()
```

As stated in [meteorpedia](http://meteorpedia.com/read/Blaze_Notes#New%20Rendered%20behaviour%20with%20external%20scripts%20e.g.%20jQuery).